# TextView multiline text line height

Tags: android

I have a TextView with AbsoluteSizeSpan. Code looks like this:

```
        String text = "And here's to you, Mrs. Robinson\nJesus loves you more than you will know";
        final SpannableStringBuilder styled = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
        AbsoluteSizeSpan sizeSpan = new AbsoluteSizeSpan(40);
        styled.setSpan(sizeSpan, 24, 32, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        Spannable spannable = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(styled);
        tv.setText(spannable);
```

With this code second line has proper height:

[image]

When `\n` is removed from text:

```
 String text = "And here's to you, Mrs. Robinson Jesus loves you more than you will know";
```

Android automatically wraps the text to next line (based on component width), but the second line has the same height as the first line:

[image]

Is there any way to force Android to make the height of line two only as big as necessary?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reduce the line-height. As of Android P (API 28), you can use [`setLineHeight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setLineHeight(int))

```java
tv.setLineHeight(int lineHeight);
```

For older versions of Android, I believe you can use [`setLineSpacing`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setLineSpacing(float,%20float)):

```java
tv.setLineSpacing(float add, float mult);
```