# Android - Line height inconsistent on a TextView if using Bold or TypefaceSpan

Tags: android, kotlin, spannablestring, line-height

I am building a reader app and have a custom class that expands a TextView with code to deal with pagination etc. The text is set from an Html format using

```
Html.fromHtml(text, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT, HtmlImageGetter(this, binding.textSurface, width), HtmlTagHandler(this))
```

It has a lot of functionalities for changing lineheights, font sizes, word spacing, etc on the fly. The layout is built with this code:

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
private fun from(layout: Layout) : Layout =
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            var tmpText = if(isUppercase) TextSegmentationNew.covertToUppercase(SpannedString(originalText)) else originalText
            val formattedText = TextSegmentationNew.formatWithWordSpacing(tmpText, wordSpacing)

            StaticLayout(
                    formattedText,
                    paint,
                    layout.width,
                    layout.alignment,
                    lineSpacingMultiplier,
                    lineSpacingExtra,
                    includeFontPadding)
        } else {
            var tmpText = if(isUppercase) TextSegmentationNew.covertToUppercase(SpannedString(originalText)) else originalText
            val formattedText = TextSegmentationNew.formatWithWordSpacing(tmpText, wordSpacing)

            StaticLayout.Builder
                    .obtain(formattedText, 0, formattedText.length, paint, layout.width)
                    .setAlignment(layout.alignment)
                    .setLineSpacing(lineSpacingExtra, lineSpacingMultiplier)
                    .setIncludePad(includeFontPadding)
                    .setUseLineSpacingFromFallbacks()
                    .setBreakStrategy(breakStrategy)
                    .setHyphenationFrequency(hyphenationFrequency)
                    .setJustificationMode()
                    .setMaxLines(maxLines)
                    .build()
        }
```

One of the functionalities is also custom coloring of the text. So for example we could color the letter a/A in a different color. I am doing this with ForegroundColorSpan which works great. The problem I have is when I try to use a StyleSpan with a BOLD typeface on a letter.

This is a text without bolding. I am drawing the top, bottom, and baseline of every line to better show the effect:
[Correct line-height when no bolding span is present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51snO.jpg)

And this is what I get when I try to bold the letter A:
[Wrong line-height on some lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmI9d.jpg)

The TextView shrinks the line-height on the lines the bold letters are on, but ONLY on the lines where there is also a new line \n character present(the red dots on the image shows these).

I tested on the devices I have here and on android 7 it works correctly but the wrong line heights show on android 8.1 and android 11. Maybe they changed something on Android 8 but I can't figure out what...

Is there a way to force the use of the correct line-height on all lines consistently no matter what spans I use?

Comment: You say it works correctly on Android 7 but not on 8.1 and 11. Does that mean it also works on Android 9, 10, 12, etc. or haven't you tested those? It may be useful to further isolate the problem. I would also look at the actual spans created between a working version and a non-working version with the simplest layout you can conjure to test. I would isolate the then create an [MVCSE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: No, I tested only on the device I have with me. So I tried to run this on different emulators and found out that it does not work on any android(even on android 7). It is probably the device that works on the exception and it is not a problem with the android version. Since the code is tied to a much bigger app, I will try and prepare an example environment with minimal code as you suggested and put it on Github to test as soon as time permits. 
I also found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67644447/textview-multiline-text-line-height 
He observes the same thing

Comment: I had the same problem, and it was related to setting the line spacing. May not be in your case, but in case you're still stuck try removing the `setLineSpacing`.